# How to Exclude Records From Active Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

I want to exclude some records from an Active Scaffold listing. I cannot find any documentation on how to do this. I see how to exclude *columns*, but I am interested in excluding *rows*. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

several options.

take a look at conditions_for_collections, beginning_of_chain or a default field_search condition.

--
Volker